# "Best of the Best" and Heavy Raiders?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, exodus

There is a card in the Battlestar Galactica: Exodus expansion called "Best of the Best".  It says:

> Play before a piloted viper makes an
>   attack.  Instead of rolling the
>   attack, roll the die and destroy that
>   many raiders in the viper's space
>   area.

Question is:

Can this card be used to destroy heavy raiders in the viper's space area?

Can it be used to destroy heavy raiders in the viper's space area if a 7 or 8 is rolled on the die?

Can it be used to destroy heavy raiders in the viper's space area if Samuel T. Anders' "Longshot" ability is used to declare that the die result is an 8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The card cannot be used to destroy Heavy Raiders. The word "Raiders" refers to normal Raiders only and not Heavy Raiders.

This is similar to the question about whether or not nukes can destroy Heavy Raiders (the card also only refers to Raiders). The [FAQ](http://fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Battlestar_Galactica/bsg_FAQ_1-1-3-new.pdf)'s answer is that nukes only destroy normal Raiders, not Heavy Raiders.

Comment: Just to clarify, the restriction on nukes mentioned doesn't apply to the result that destroys all ships.